# batch image augment in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-augmentation

I want to do image augmentation, for example, rotate random angle in tensorflow. In each batch, I wanna rotate different random angles for every single image. I can do it by using `tf.contrib.image.rotate` to `image_batch` with randomly generated angle tensor:

```
radian = tf.random_uniform(
    (batch_size),  
    minval=-ROT_TH,
    maxval=ROT_TH,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    seed=None,
    name=None
)
rotated_batch = tf.contrib.image.rotate(image_batch, radian)
```

However, if I build batch with `allow_smaller_final_batch=True`, the `batch_size` is useless because the `image_batch` will not have fixed batch size. And the rotate will fail because the N dimension of radian and image_batch is not the same.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating the images in batch, I applied the same rotation to the images from `image_queue.deque()`:

```
images = load_images(filenames, options)
radian = tf.random_uniform([len(images)], ...)
images =  tf.contrib.image.rotate(images, radian)

image_batch = tf.train.batch_join([images, filenames],
                                  enqueue_many=True, allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
                                  batch_size=WHATEVER)
```